# How to add ubuntu 12.10 entry to grub menu list?

Tags: ubuntu-12.10, grub

I removed my ubuntu 12.10 entry while editing `menu.lst` file.

can anyone give me a sample file containing the ubuntu 12.10 entry in `menu.lst` file.

It should be something like this:

```
title Ubuntu 12.10
      kernel 
      initrd
```

my ubuntu installation is on `sda6`.

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try calling `sudo update-grub` from console. It will write a new standard configuration

Comment: this does not help. i need to get it from someone. i need the menu.lst entry in text.

Comment: As long as you are still running ubuntu [this will help!](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-grub.8.html)...Getting it from someone else will not help, its specific for your configuration. But you can use any of [these helps too](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=menu.lst)

Comment: I'm not working in ubuntu. i actually need exactly that line of code to enter in menu.lst. someone just can copy and paste the menu.lst file content here and that's all. can you help, please?

Comment: This question should be moved to the Ubuntu site: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: See this: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/menu.lst#Liste-automatisch-generierter-Menueeintraege

Comment: @sonyakochooloo Did you install an older version of Grub? 12.10 uses grub 2 by default and instead uses the grub.cfg file and has since 9.10

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Grub2 per my comment above and have not installed a non-default bootloader, here is an example menu entry from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 862e9bd8-8641-478a-96a3-d5ad9a53b104
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=862e9bd8-8641-478a-96a3-d5ad9a53b104 ro find_preseed=/preseed.cfg noprompt  quiet
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
}
```

As you can see, the root drives are set via uuid, so cutting and pasting a solution will not work for you.

However you can try the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility, or follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

If you have installed an older version of grub [this blog post](http://boff.wordpress.com/2007/01/17/editing-bootgrubmenulst-to-change-the-grub-boot-menu/) gives some examples you may find useful.